# Not able to locate elements on Mobile using Appium Android

Tags: android, appium

On using Appium for Android and app as Amazon, I am not able to find any of the elements on page. It's giving me the following error :

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 10.15 seconds
>   For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
>   Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'
>   System info: host: 'poojal03', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
>   Session ID: c8910730-dab7-43bc-a22f-53e4e3627885
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
>   Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, app=C:\Users\poojal\Desktop\com.amazon.mShop.android-5.5.0.200-5050002-minAPI9.apk, javascriptEnabled=true, appActivity=com.amazon.mShop.splashscreen.StartupActivity, browserName=, networkConnectionEnabled=true, desired={app=C:\Users\poojal\Desktop\com.amazon.mShop.android-5.5.0.200-5050002-minAPI9.apk, platformName=Android, deviceName=BX903GLKY4, browserName=, appActivity=com.amazon.mShop.splashscreen.StartupActivity, appPackage=com.amazon.mShop.android, version=4.4.4}, locationContextEnabled=false, appPackage=com.amazon.mShop.android, version=4.4.4, platformVersion=4.1, databaseEnabled=false, platformName=Android, deviceName=BX903GLKY4, webStorageEnabled=false, warnings={}, takesScreenshot=true}]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:352)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:393)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:214)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
>       at Amazon.main(Amazon.java:57)

Comment: This question doesn't say anything. Please share code and error which line you are having this error.

Comment: Debugging this would require your framed code to access the elements. Issue broadly means Appium could not find out an element on the view where you were looking for. But using what is missing in the question.

Comment: your logs doesnot say much to debug. No such element means not able to get the element so question is your element provided is correct? how did u identify that locator? did runtime locators changes? Sometimes Locators are present in the DOM but not visible So even that time you may get this error. try to introduce some wait/sleep before u hit the Locator . if possible share the code to get more details for analysis .

Answer (score -1):

By looking at the logs it saying time out exception. It can happens if respective page took long time to load or invalid xpath. If you can share a screenshot of the inspector/ uiautomatorviewer and your written xpath for the element, I can provide a direct answer

Comment: ask this in comment section , need not to be posted as an answer